mariadb ssl problem: ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Validation of SSL server certificate failed
this will be extremely detailed as I can't solve this problem. I have a website developed with java servlet and jdbc, whose connection method is:
private static synchronized Connection createDBConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection newConnection = null;
        String ip = "localhost";
        String port = "3306";
        String db = "bookscape";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String truststorePath = "/opt/jdk-21.0.3/lib/security/cacerts";
        String truststorePassword = "changeit";

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststorePath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorePassword);

        newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + db +
            "?     useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Rome&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&requireSSL=true",
            username, password
        );

        newConnection.setAutoCommit(true);

        // verify if ssl is used
        try (Statement stmt = newConnection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'")){
            if (rs.next()) {
                String sslCipher = rs.getString("Value");
                if (sslCipher != null && !sslCipher.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("SSL è attivo. Cifrario SSL utilizzato: " + sslCipher);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("SSL non è attivo.");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Errore durante la verifica dell'SSL: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return newConnection;
    }

I configured the mysql server 50-server.cnf configuration file with:
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/certs/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/certs/server-key.pem
require-secure-transport = on

ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2`


and 50-client.cnf con:
[client]
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem
ssl-key  = /etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem
ssl-verify-server-cert = on

the certificates are all in mysql/certs, I also added them to the default java truststore (cacerts). Now, if I start tomcat, the site works and if I look in catalina.out, I see from the logs that the encryption is happening (console.log in the java code). So everything's fine, right? ssl configured well and in use, no problems. If instead I try to access mysql from the terminal I get: ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Validation of SSL server certificate failed. Why? what's the reason?
further context, in ~/.bashrc I added:
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.91
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-21.0.3
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apr/lib"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jdk-21.0.3/lib/security/cacerts \
                  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

also, the tomcat server and mariadb are running on the same machine (raspberry pi 4)
I tried to check the certificates, everything was ok (on the other hand the connection from Java works as expected), I tried to change permissions, but there was nothing to do there either, I checked in the truststore and the certificates are all there.

The error message is a little bit too general, since it doesn't tell you what exactly went wrong (this will be fixed in MariaDB Connector/C 3.4.1).
The peer certificate is validated in 2 steps:
Step 1 checks if the certificate is trusted:

Check if the certificate is self signed (since you pass a ca file which contains the server cert this will pass)
Check if the certificate was revoked (CRL)
Check if the current GMT Time is between notBefore and NotAfter

Step 2 checks the hostname of the trusted certificate (see RFC6125):

If Step1 succeeded, the hostname will be validated.

In your case it seems that the hostname stored in CN (or alternative name) doesn't match the hostname which you specified in command line client.
About your configuration:
ssl_cipher=TLSv1.2
This is not portable, it will work only if the client was built with OpenSSL, but not with GuTLS or Schannel. Instead use tls_version=TLSv1.2.
ssl_certand ssl_key in [client] section
This is only required if your user was defined with the REQUIRE X509 option. Otherwise, unnecessary overhead is created because the client has to send data that is not processed by the server.
